# linux copy directory over another directory and if the same rename older files appending the modification date-time

Tags: linux, find, cp, xargs, xcopy

In Linux, I am wondering how one can copy (maybe some sort of merge) one directory over the second directory - which can have the same name - and if two file have the same name then rename whichever file is older appending the modification date-time and copy?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: You might want to have a look at `rsync`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I did look at rsync. The idea is to be able to rename the file by have it appended with its modification time if there is a file with the same name in the destination and if there is not the same file as well - so if exists then compare and if different copy and rename the older copy with the file name appended with its modification date-time and if (else) the same ignore. Rsync allows - if I not mistaken - to do just a backup if the same exists.